# General solution of 2-nd order ODE with power-law term and parametric constants

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to get a general solution to the given differential equation. What substitution I'm supposed to apply to get the solution? `ρ,Ω` and `γ` are constants.

```
eq = (x + ρ)^2 y''[x] + 
   3 ρ (x + ρ) y'[x] + 
   (9^-ρ γ^(-2 ρ) Ω^2 (x + ρ)^(2 - 2 ρ) + 2 ρ - 8 ρ^2) y[x] == 0
```

Comment: Have you tried `DSolve`?

Comment: You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Maple 2022 answers $y\! \left(x\right)=\textit{_}\mathit{C1} \left(x+\rho \right)^{-\frac{3 \rho}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{BesselJ}\! \left(-\frac{\sqrt{41 \rho^{2}-14 \rho +1}}{2 \rho -2},\frac{\Omega  \sqrt{9^{-\rho} \gamma^{-2 \rho}}\, \left(x+\rho \right)^{1-\rho}}{-1+\rho}\right)+\textit{_}\mathit{C2} \left(x+\rho \right)^{-\frac{3 \rho}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{BesselY}\! \left(-\frac{\sqrt{41 \rho^{2}-14 \rho +1}}{2 \rho -2},\frac{\Omega  \sqrt{9^{-\rho} \gamma^{-2 \rho}}\, \left(x+\rho \right)^{1-\rho}}{-1+\rho}\right)$.

Comment: The above is produced by `dsolve((x + rho)^2*diff(y(x), x, x) + 3*rho*(x + rho)*diff(y(x), x) + (9^(-rho)*g^(-2*rho)*Omega^2*(x + rho)^(2 - 2*rho) + 2*rho - 8*rho^2)*y(x) = 0, y(x));` (`g` instead of `gamma` for a technical reason).

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the factor `(x + ρ)^(2 - 2 ρ)` with a parameter in an exponent in one of the coefficients makes this a DE that `DSolve` cannot handle.  If we replace `ρ` with an explicit integer, then the solution is a holonomic function, which falls within the scope of `DSolve` and for large values of `ρ`, `DifferentialRoot`.

Examples:

```
Table[DSolve[eq, y, x], {ρ, 4}]
```

[image]

From `ρ = 3` to `ρ = 5`, we get solutions in terms of `BesselI[]`, and it seems there might be a pattern; but three might not be enough terms to guess the pattern.
Anyway, it seems to hint at a path of investigation.
For `ρ = 6` and higher, we get a `DifferentialRoot`, which won't expand to an explicit formula:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But I need a parametric solution. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Find general solution with variable transformation `(x + \[Rho])^(2 - 2 \[Rho]) -> z`, although not valid for all cases.

```
eq = Expand[
   eq = (x + \[Rho])^2 y''[x] + 
      3 \[Rho] (x + \[Rho]) y'[
        x] + (9^-\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(-2 \[Rho]) \[CapitalOmega]^2 (x + \
\[Rho])^(2 - 2 \[Rho]) + 2 \[Rho] - 8 \[Rho]^2) y[x] == 0];

eq2 = eq /. y -> (y[(# + \[Rho])^(2 - 2 \[Rho])] &) // Expand

sol = Flatten@Solve[z == (x + \[Rho])^(2 - 2 \[Rho]), x]
```

This transformation and further equalities below are not valid for all x-rho combinations. Use `Reduce[z == (x + \[Rho])^(2 - 2 \[Rho]), x, Reals]`  to get further information. I use it here to show how to proceed in general.

```
eq3 = eq2 /. sol

eq4 = eq3 /. (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 2 \[Rho]) -> z // Expand

Together /@ ( 
  z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(-2 \[Rho]) // 
   PowerExpand)

(*   z   *)

Together /@ ((z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 2 \[Rho]) // PowerExpand)

(*   z   *)

Together /@ ( 
  z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 4 \[Rho]) // 
   PowerExpand)

(*   z^2   *)

eq5 = eq4 /. 
    z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(-2 \[Rho]) -> 
     z /. (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 2 \[Rho]) -> z /. 
  z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 4 \[Rho]) -> z^2

dsol5 = DSolve[eq5, y, z]

(*   {{y -> Function[{z}, 
    2^(Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))
       3^(\[Rho] (Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
         2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
          1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)))
       z^((-1 + 3 \[Rho] - Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       4 (-1 + \[Rho])) + 
       1/2 (-(Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
           2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
           1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
          2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))) \[Gamma]^(\[Rho] (Sqrt[
         1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
         2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
          1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
         2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))) (-1 + \[Rho])^(
      Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) (4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) - 
        8 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho] + 
        4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho]^2)^(-((-1 + 3 \[Rho] - 
        Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       4 (-1 + \[Rho])))) \[CapitalOmega]^(-(Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
        2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) + (-1 + 3 \[Rho] - Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 (-1 + \[Rho])))
       BesselJ[-(Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
        2 (-1 + \[Rho]))), (2 Sqrt[z] \[CapitalOmega])/Sqrt[
       4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) - 
        8 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho] + 
        4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho]^2]] C[1] Gamma[
       2/(2 - 2 \[Rho]) - (2 \[Rho])/(2 - 2 \[Rho]) + Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(2 - 2 \[Rho])] + 
     2^(-(Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
        2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))
       3^(\[Rho] (-(Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
          2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
          1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)))
       z^((-1 + 3 \[Rho] + Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       4 (-1 + \[Rho])) + 
       1/2 (Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
          2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
           1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
          2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))) \[Gamma]^(\[Rho] (-(Sqrt[
          1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
          2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
          1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
         2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2))) (-1 + \[Rho])^(-(Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
        2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) + (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2)) (4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) - 
        8 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho] + 
        4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho]^2)^(-((-1 + 3 \[Rho] + 
        Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       4 (-1 + \[Rho])))) \[CapitalOmega]^(
      Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) - (\[Rho] Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(
       2 - 4 \[Rho] + 2 \[Rho]^2) + (-1 + 3 \[Rho] + Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2])/(2 (-1 + \[Rho])))
       BesselJ[Sqrt[1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(2 (-1 + \[Rho])), (
       2 Sqrt[z] \[CapitalOmega])/Sqrt[
       4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) - 
        8 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho] + 
        4 9^\[Rho] \[Gamma]^(2 \[Rho]) \[Rho]^2]] C[
       2] Gamma[-(1/(-1 + \[Rho])) + \[Rho]/(-1 + \[Rho]) + Sqrt[
        1 - 14 \[Rho] + 41 \[Rho]^2]/(2 (-1 + \[Rho]))]]}}   *)
```

See, where used equalities are not valid

```
Plot3D[Re[
  z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(-2 \[Rho])], {z, -5, 
  5}, {\[Rho], -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100]

Plot3D[Re[
  z^(2/(2 - 2 \[Rho])) (z^(1/(2 - 2 \[Rho])))^(2 - 4 \[Rho])], {z, -5,
   5}, {\[Rho], -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Finaly backtransformate from z to x. (Didn't do intensiv testing of the range of validity of the result dsol)